# Lambda function in VPC doesn't access to cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-vpc

I am new to working with lambda functions. I have a very simple problem I think. I have a lambda function that collects metrics from an external server and then sends them to Cloudwatch.
Everything works fine until I add a VPC to the lambda function, the metrics from the external server are collected correctly but when it gets to the part of putting the metrics (`cw.put_metric_data(...)`) it immediately throws me `Timeout`.
What can I be doing wrong?

**Fixed:**

- The solution was to increase the waiting time to 3 minutes.

Comment: What is your setting for how long the script is allowed to run? I think the default is 3 sec.

Comment: Yes, the default value is 3 seconds. I tried to increase this to 1m30sec and it gave Timeout again.

Answer (score 1):

A lambda function without VPC configuration has free access to the public Internet and some AWS services by default. However, when you configure a VPC, you only have access to the resources within that VPC. To mitigate this problem you can setup a VPC endpoint to enable private communications between your VPC and supported AWS services as explained in the [VPC developer docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/privatelink/create-interface-endpoint.html#create-interface-endpoint-aws). Specifically for CloudWatch, the service to choose is `com.amazonaws.Region.logs` as stated in the [CloudWatch documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/cloudwatch-logs-and-interface-VPC.html#create-VPC-endpoint-for-CloudWatchLogs).